# Which folder to keep projects for Homebrew nginx port 8080

Tags: macos, nginx, homebrew

I am using macbook and installed nginx using Homebrew from the terminal. I think i installed 2-3 versions of nginx in different locations. Now I can see my http://localhost:8080/ is working as it displays nginx home page in browser but how can I place my projects inside nginx? I tried to put those in one of the nginx directory but it does not work if if I try to go to project through browser.
Is there anything from where I can find the exact directory of this running version of nginx?

Comment: There isn't really a right answer here -- you should be writing your own config file that specifies where code, static content, &c. is retrieved from.

Comment: that said, "installed nginx using terminal" -- how, *exactly*? Did you use MacPorts? Homebrew? Something else? (If we know the packaging system, we can look at the default configuration used by that package).

Comment: @charles .. I used Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `brew list` command:

```
$ brew list nginx
/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.10.1/bin/nginx
/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.10.1/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.10.1/html -> ../../../var/www
/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.10.1/share/man/man8/nginx.8
$ greadlink -f /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.10.1/html
/usr/local/var/www
```

Thus, the symlink links to `/usr/local/var/www`, and default configuration is likely to do likewise.

Comment: You don't need to run the `greadlink` command yourself -- it just makes the target of the link easier to read. Assuming your link is in the same place and has the same contents, the result will be identical. (That said, I use MacPorts rather than homebrew -- a rather strongly-held preference, since Homebrew weakens a system's security by having executables owned by an otherwise-unprivileged user account rather than requiring the user to use `sudo` -- and installed GNU readlink, with the rest of the suite of standard tools, via the `coreutils` port).